# Matplotlib - duplicated axes - prevent gridlines from covering data - set right ylabel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to duplicate axes so that I can express an exponent in terms of its doubling time.

I think I am doing things right, but I have two problems

- no label on the right hand side of the chart and
- y-axis gridlines that are plotted above the data that I cannot shift to the bottom, nor remove.

Example code follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MARGINS = 0.02

data = pd.Series(np.arange(0.05, 1.0, 0.1))

# preliminaries
plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.figure.set_size_inches((8, 4))
ax.set_ylabel('$k$') # This works
ax.margins(MARGINS)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)

# duplicate the axes
axr = ax.twinx().twiny()
axr.margins(MARGINS)
axr.set_ylabel('Doubling time') # This does not work
    
# No x-ticks at the top
axr.xaxis.set_ticks([])
axr.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
        
# plot the data
ax.plot(data.index, data)

# label right-hand y-axis
locations = ax.get_yticks()
new_labels = [f'{np.log(2)/x:,.2f}' if x != 0 else '∞' for x in locations ]
axr.yaxis.set_ticks(locations)
axr.yaxis.set_ticklabels(new_labels)
axr.set_axisbelow(True) # this does not work

# match the left and right ylim settings
axr.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()) 
axr.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())

# remove the grid
axr.grid(False, which='both')
axr.yaxis.grid(False, which='both') # this does not work

# finish-up
ax.set_title('Chart')
fig.tight_layout(pad=1.1)
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

[image: Output from above code]

Desired output:
Similar chart to above but with:

- a right hand side y-axis label
- no y-axis gridlines over the data line (but keep the horizontal gridlines under the dataline)

Comment: I want to keep all gridlines, just don't want them on top of the data line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of `twiny` and `twinx`:

```py
axr = ax.twiny().twinx()
```

[image: twiny-twinx]